# alias in subselect of select possible in any way

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

Clarification: I'm using jdbc over jpql native query with mysql

```
em.createNativeQuery(MyQuery).getResultList();
```

Is it possible to do what's written below in one such MyQuery string? Without having to create temporal tables, views, stored procedures or execute other statements. If NO then simple NO will be fine, maybe an explication on why not would be welcome.

I would like to use B in subselect inside select

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B) CNT FROM
```

where B is an alias of an other select.

```
 (SELECT * FROM XY) B
```

this could be anywhere like:

```
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM XY) B ON ...
```

This does not work, but the question is:

Is it possible to do this in a single query any (other) way (without having to create a view)?

basically I want to use a select result set in a select which is in a select clause (for example to count something there). And I want to reuse it in different parts of the query, therefore the alias is needed.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.  Your first query is likely to return an error unless `B` has exactly one column and zero or one rows.  Please edit the question and provide more details.

Comment: you need to SELECT x,y,z FROM (SELECT * FROM B) for your query t make sense.  You can SELECT x,y,z FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT a AS x, b as y FROM XY)) if you want inner, inner selects

Comment: Please write more clear and concise questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like a CTE table:

```
With B (columnA, columnB) as
(
Select columnA, columnB
  from XY
)

Select count(*)
  From B
```

Or for MySQL:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE B (columnA varchar(10), columnB varchar(20))
Insert into B (columnA, columnB) values
select columnA, columnB
  from XY

Select count(*)
  From B
```

Comment: Actually yes, but without CTE (it is not supported by mysql), so you say all I can do now is create a temp table or view?

Comment: Yes that would probably be the best way around it as far as I'm aware

Comment: That would be fine if I could use it in one sql statement returning a result set. Can I? To me it looks like those are two separate statements, I just would like to avoid creating views or using stored procedures (I need single jdbc select)

Comment: This should be fine as a single query, I'm not a jdbc expert though but you could try it and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use a trick with variables to accomplish this:

```
SELECT b.*, @cnt
FROM (SELECT b.*, @cnt := @cnt + 1 as cnt
      FROM b CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @cnt := 0) vars
     ) b;
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't solve this with variables, I need a full result set to work on.

Comment: @user1132655 . . . Your comment doesn't make sense.